# Strapi Entity Service API $between does not filter by date?

Tags: cron, strapi

I am attempting to filter content pieces that are between 3 and 30 days old and then change their related category. I am doing this via cron jobs so that it can happen every day at midnight. However, even though I have content pieces that fit this category, none are being retrieved and updated. Does the $between filter work with dates? Or only integers? Please see associated code below.

```
"0 0 * * *": async ({strapi}) => {
        let threeDaysAgo = new Date();
        let twentyNineDaysAgo = new Date() ;
        threeDaysAgo.setDate(threeDaysAgo.getDate() - 3);
        twentyNineDaysAgo.setDate(twentyNineDaysAgo.getDate() - 29);
        console.log(threeDaysAgo, "Three days ago")
        console.log(twentyNineDaysAgo, "Twenty Nine days ago");
        const oldJobs = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::job.job', {
           filters: {
            createdAt: {
                $between:[threeDaysAgo, twentyNineDaysAgo]
            }
        },
        });

        console.log(oldJobs, "Old Jobs")

        for (let job of oldJobs){
            console.log(job)
            await strapi.entityService.update("api::job.job",job.id, {
                data:{
                    jobAge:{
                        set:[{id:2}]
                    },
        }
    })
        }
    },
```

I have tried a variety of different ways to grab the date element to no avail. If I try other filtering options like $lt or $gt, it appears to work just fine. But $between does not.

Comment: Likely a bug in strapi, and you need to use UNIX timestamp integer as a value…